# ee.List map function, using value to filter ee.Featureset

Tags: google-earth-engine-javascript-api, filter, mapping

I am converting the image into a vector, but because it might return more that 5000 features I want to `union` all the features that have the same elevation property.

I run the following code, but the geometry of the features is always empty, if I use a hardcoded value for `value`, then all works as expected. I am guessing that `value` is not yet evaluated at the time when I want to filter. How would I fix this, or how can I rewrite this in order to make it work, I cannot make the scale any higher to lower the number of features, nor do I want to export the FeatureCollection to disk

```
var elevation = ee.Image('NASA/NASADEM_HGT/001')
  .select('elevation')
  .clip(boundary)
  .uint16()
  .reduceToVectors({ geometry : boundary, scale : 200 })

var unique = elevation.aggregate_histogram('label').keys()
var features = unique.map(function(value) {
  var filtered = elevation.filter(ee.Filter.eq('label', value)) // turning value into hard coded number works like expected
  var feature = filtered.union(1).first();
  feature = feature.set({ value : value });
  return feature;
});

print(features.get(0));
```

I expect that `features.get(0)` would give me a `Feature` with the geometry of the filtered `FeatureCollection` as a `MultiPolygon`. But the geometry is empty and only the property is set with the correct value, if I use a hardcoded value all works as expected.